# Why my UISwitches states are always ON?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a TableView with custom cells with a UILabel and a UISwitch, and I would like to ON/OFF the switch of a cell when a row is selected.

The problem is when I fetch my UISwitch in the `didSelectRowRowAtIndexPath()` method, is state is always on ON (even if I put it to OFF in the emulator), and the `setOn()` method doesn't do anything...

I was thinking maybe the switch fetched was not the good one, but when I display the label of a cell, it is the good one...

My cell :

```
class CourseResourceCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var mNameCourseResourceLabel: UILabel!

}
```

My code in the tableView :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println(courseResourceCellAtIndexPath(indexPath).mNameCourseResourceLabel.text)
        var courseResourceSwitch = courseResourceCellAtIndexPath(indexPath).mSwitch
        if courseResourceSwitch.on {
            println("ON to OFF")
            courseResourceSwitch.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            courseResourceCellAtIndexPath(indexPath).mSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
        }
        else {
            println("OFF to ON")
            courseResourceSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
        }
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return courseResourceCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }

    func courseResourceCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CourseResourceCell {
        let cell = self.mTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CourseResourceReuseIdentifier) as! CourseResourceCell
        setCourseResourceNameForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func setCourseResourceNameForCell(cell :CourseResourceCell, indexPath :NSIndexPath) {
        let courseResource = courseResourcesList[indexPath.row] as CourseResource
        if var label = cell.mNameCourseResourceLabel {
            label.text = courseResource.name
        }

        let leftMarginConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.mSwitch, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell.mSwitch.superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, multiplier: CGFloat(courseResource.level!), constant: 1)
        cell.mSwitch.superview!.addConstraint(leftMarginConstraint)
    }
```

Comment: My Error in code is  use of unresolved identifier ''courceResorce List"?What is the courseResourcesList and CourseResource in below answer?Please give details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing with has to do with reusable cells. By calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you are using same cell for all records in your tableview and changing view state directly as you do may also affect other views as well. To solve this you must somehow save cell state in your data source, ex. declare a variable `isOn` in `CourseResource` and after selecting a cell change the value of this variable and reload that cell after.

Some concrete implementation :

```
func setCourseResourceNameForCell(cell :CourseResourceCell, indexPath :NSIndexPath) {
    let courseResource = courseResourcesList[indexPath.row] as CourseResource
    if var label = cell.mNameCourseResourceLabel {
        label.text = courseResource.name
    }

    if courseResource.isOn{
        cell.mSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }else{
        cell.mSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }

    let leftMarginConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.mSwitch, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell.mSwitch.superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, multiplier: CGFloat(courseResource.level!), constant: 1)
    cell.mSwitch.superview!.addConstraint(leftMarginConstraint)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  var courseResource = courseResourcesList[indexPath.row] as CourseResource      

  if courseResource.isOn {
        courseResource.isOn = false
  }else{
       courseResource.isOn = true
  }

  tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
  tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Here,What is the courseResourcesList and CourseResource?Please give details

Comment: @Zell My Error in code is use of unresolved identifier ''courceResorce List"?.